# Rails 4 - threading error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to perform some calculations to populate some historic data in the database.

The database is SQL Server.  The server is tomcat (using JRuby).

I am running the script file in a rails console pointed to the uat environment.

I am trying to use threads to speed up the execution.  The idea being that each thread would take an object and run the calculations for it, and save the calculated values back to the database.

Problem:  I keep getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError (could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds))
```

code:

```
require 'thread'

    threads = []
    items_to_calculate = Item.where("id < 11").to_a #testing only 10 items for now

    for item in items_to_calculate
      threads << Thread.new(item) { |myitem|

        my_calculator = ItemsCalculator.new(myitem)
        to_save = my_calculator.calculate_details
        to_save.each do |dt|
          dt.save!
        end
      }
    end

    threads.each { |aThread|  aThread.join }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably spawning more threads than ActiveRecord's DB connection pool has connections. [Ekkehard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920561/802618) is an excellent general description; so here's a simple example of how to limit your workers using Ruby's thread-safe `Queue`.

```
require 'thread'

queue = Queue.new
items.each { |i| queue << i } # Fill the queue

Array.new(5) do # Only 5 concurrent workers
  Thread.new do
    until queue.empty?
      item = queue.pop
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        # Work
      end
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

I chose 5 because that's the [ConnectionPool's default](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html), but you can certainly tune that to the max that still works, or populate another queue with the result to save later and run an arbitrary number of threads for the calculation.

The `with_connection` method grabs a connection, runs your block, then ensures the connection is released. It's necessary because of a bug in `ActiveRecord` where the connection doesn't always get released otherwise. Check out [this blog post](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2016/02/14/ruby-threads-and-active-record-connections/) for some details.

Comment: Thanks for this, how do I do the "work" and pass in my item?

Comment: The `item` is already there for you - see `item = queue.pop`? Blocks have access to the variables defined in their lexical scope.

Comment: Thanks, I notcied that after I commented.  I changed my code but I still get the timeout error.  I can post my whole code if you need

Comment: Try starting with 1 thread and working your way up until you find a limit. If there are other things going on in your application, you might not have access to the entire pool. If that still doesn't work, try filling a second `Queue` with the result of the work, then save your items in serial once everything's done.

Comment: That's weird. I can't debug without access to your entire app, but try stripping off the Array and Thread wrappers, and just process the queue with no concurrency at all. If that still fails, something else is going on - maybe in `ItemCalculator`?

Comment: It works fine in a normal loop with no threads, takes 14 seconds for 1 'item'  - I was trying to improve on that

Comment: You can also try increasing your DB connection pool in `config/database.yml` by setting eg. `development.pool`.

Answer (score 1):

You are potentially starting a huge amount of threads at the same time if you leave the testing stage.

Each of these threads will need a DB connection. Either Rails is going to create a new one for every thread (possible creating a huge amount of DB connections at the same time), or it does not, in which case you'll run into trouble because several threads are trying to use the same connection in parallel. The first case would explain the error message because there will probably be a hard limit of open DB connections in your DB server.

Creating threads like this is usually not advisable. You're usually better off to create a handful (controlled/limited) amount of worker threads and using a queue to distribute work between them.

In your case, you could have a set of worker threads to do the calculations, and a second set of worker threads to write to the DB. I do not know enough about the details of your code to decide for you which is better.  If the calculation is expensive and the DB-work is not, then you will probably have only one worker for writing to the DB in a serial fashion. If your DB is a beast and highly optimized for parallel writing and you need to write a lot of data, then you will maybe want a (small) amount of DB workers.

Comment: I'd say the calculations are not performant, since they are using eval on a string to calculate a formula, as well as using BigDecimal. The calculate_details method could perform 30-40 calculations.  Could you post a code example?